# unity 3d teleport OnCollisionEnter with tag not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a few scripts im trying to get to work with tags, I thought the scripts were working until I made my teleoprter script.  The collider part must be wrong but I cant figure out how or why the tag part isnt working.  when the collider tag is called it calls all the scripts with the on oncollisionenter part

I'll show you the 2 codes I tried
the 2 tags are "CC" and "Door"

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider CC)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "CC") 
    {
        Debug.Log ("Combat Chance Roll");
        isCombat = false;
        CombatChance = Random.Range (1, 100);
        Probability = 20;

        if (CombatChance <= Probability) {
            isCombat = true;
            isCombat2 = true;
        } else {
            isCombat = false;
            isCombat2 = false;
        }
    }
```

---

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider Door)
{
    if (collider.gameObject.tag == "Door") 
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.51f, -17.0f);
    }
}
```

these are 2 separate scripts, both on the player, looking for the collider tag

so when I hit the Door i teleport and check do the CombatChanceRoll
I only want to call the Door not both. and vice versa

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

code that i got to work but not sure if there's a better way

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider CC)
{
    switch (CC.tag) 
    {
        case "CC":
        Debug.Log ("Combat Chance Roll");
        isCombat = false;
        CombatChance = Random.Range (1, 100);
        Probability = 20;

        if (CombatChance <= Probability) {
            isCombat = true;
            isCombat2 = true;
        } else {
            isCombat = false;
            isCombat2 = false;
        }
        break;
    }
```

Comment: Comment every code in the CC ontrigger function put this code there  `Debug.Log("Collided in CC with: "+collider.gameObject.tag);`. then in the Second ontrigger function, comment every code there and add this `Debug.Log("Collided in Door with: "+collider.gameObject.tag);`. Report back with the exact Log you got from each function.

Comment: They were colliding with the Player. I thought It would be the player is colliding with CC or the Door. I found one solution but I'm not sure if there's a better or more correct way

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing your `if` statement to `switch` statement will **NOT** solve your problem. I just took a closer look at your code and I see two mistakes in your code.

Change  `if (collider.gameObject.tag == "CC")`

to

```
if (CC.gameObject.tag == "CC")
```

Then Change if `(collider.gameObject.tag == "Door")`

to

```
if (Door.gameObject.tag == "Door")
```

So your final Code should look like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider CC)
{
    if (CC.gameObject.tag == "CC") 
    {
        Debug.Log ("Combat Chance Roll");
        isCombat = false;
        CombatChance = Random.Range (1, 100);
        Probability = 20;

        if (CombatChance <= Probability) {
            isCombat = true;
            isCombat2 = true;
        } else {
            isCombat = false;
            isCombat2 = false;
        }
    }
```

**AND**

```
void OnTriggerEnter (Collider Door)
{
    if (Door.gameObject.tag == "Door") 
    {
        transform.position = new Vector3 (0.0f, 0.51f, -17.0f);
    }
}
```

Also **avoid** comparing tags with `==` or  with the **switch** statement. Use the `CompareTag` function instead. For example,  `if (CC.gameObject.CompareTag("CC"))` and `if (Door.gameObject.CompareTag("Door"))`

Comment: This worked!  Thanks for the tips on how the compare tags worked. I've been trying for 2 days now to get this working right

Comment: Glad I was able to help you.